# TinyMCE Popup displaying blank page

Tags: popup, tinymce

I'm installing TinyMCE on a site of ours.  All seems to of installed fine apart from a problem I am having with the popup windows for image, html etc etc.  The popup's appear to be empty but when I view the source, the code is there but there is inline styling on the body to display: none.
Does anybody know why this is happening?

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at the popup page using something like Firebug in Firefox, or the error console in Safari/Chrome? There may be a file that's not loading. Otherwise, can you let us know what TinyMCE configuration you are using and what browser(s) this is happening on.